# Overwrite Content in PHP fwrite()

Tags: php, file-io

Is there any way you can overwrite a line in PHP. let me be a little more clearer using examples.

**My array**

```
array{
    [DEVICE] => eth0,
    [IPADDR] => 192.168.0.2,
    [NETMASK] => 255.255.255.0,
    [NETWORK] => 192.168.0.0,
    [BROADCAST] => 255.255.255.255,
    [GATEWAY] => 192.168.0.1,
    [ONBOOT] => no
}
```

**File im overwriting**

```
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=192.168.200.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.200.0
BROADCAST=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=192.168.200.1
ONBOOT=no
DNS1=195.100.10.1
```

**Result of the File that is rewritten**

```
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.0.0
BROADCAST=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
ONBOOT=no
DNS1=195.100.10.1
```

Note that `DNS1=195.100.10.1` Stays in the file becuase it dosent have a key with the value of `DNS` in our array.

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to overwrite the entire file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235604/overwite-line-in-file-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find an algorithm to do it :

1. Read the file to overwrite with the `file()` function (look carefully at the options, you don't want the news line char to be included in the array).
2. Loop through the array and `explode()` each element to create a new key => value array.
3. Merge the obtained array with your first array.
4. Implode back each items of the new array
5. Overwrite the file by imploding the array with \n

Comment: Ohhh Merge just might save me a massive pain in the ass

Answer (score 2):

I've done it before by reading the whole file in a variable and then using preg_replace to replace the various variables I wanted to change.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second  webbiedave's comment. You could only seek into the appropriate position and then use fwrite if the what you were writing over had the same size of what you're writing (it's not the case).