# Replace the header of csv without loading the whole csv in memory in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV of size 5GB and more. I need to replace the header of the CSV with one different header string. I am looking for a memory-efficient solution in `PHP` where I won't need to read the whole CSV in memory just to replace the header.

Comment: try [league/csv](https://csv.thephpleague.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a line in a file without rewriting the entire file (in PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030804/replacing-a-line-in-a-file-without-rewriting-the-entire-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I would use some combination of head&tail&echo in bash running in `symfony/process`. That's usually safest and most memory efficient.