# How to replace text file data with form using php?

Tags: php

I've a text file.Now i want to replace text data with a form (POST or GET) in PHP.
My text file like that-

```
"
Mr.A                         
87362                
Mr.B           
87427         
Mr.C          
85423
"
```

Now if i want to change Mr.A to Mr.H with a form submit POST or GET method,what should i do?

Comment: You really want to be using a database for this, it's not hard.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever yo have to change a text file, you always have to read it into memory, do string manipulation and write the whole thing to a file again.

This explains a lot [Overwrite Line in File with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235604/overwrite-line-in-file-with-php)

Assuming you can get your variables from your POST request, you should be able to follow the solution in the above link to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
  <?php  
  $n="filename.txt";
  $f=fopen($n,'r');
  $c=fread($f,100);
  $final = str_replace("Mr.A ", "Mr.".$_POST['field'], $c);
  fclose($f);
  $f=fopen($n,'w');
  fwrite($f,$final);
  fclose($f);
  ?>
```