# How to change the first 512 bytes of a file?

Tags: php, file, file-io, stream

I have got a large file in PHP of which I would like to replace the first 512 bytes with some other 512 bytes. Is there any PHP function that helps me with that?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to optionally create a file and read and write to it (without truncating it), you need to open the file with the [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) function in `'c+'` mode:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'c+');
```

PHP then has the [`stream_get_contents()`](http://php.net/stream_get_contents) function which allows to read a chunk of bytes with a specific length (and from a specific offset in the file) into a string variable:

```
$buffer = stream_get_contents($handle, $length = 512, $offset = 0);
```

However, there is no `stream_put_contents()` function to write the string buffer back to the stream at a specific position/offset. A related function is [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) but it does not allow to write to a file-handle resource at a specific offset. But there is [`fseek()`](http://php.net/fseek) and [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/fwrite) to do that:

```
$bytes_written = false;
if (0 === fseek($handle, $offset)) {
    $bytes_written = fwrite($handle, $buffer, $length);
}
```

Here is the full picture:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'c+');
$buffer = stream_get_contents($handle, $length = 512, $offset = 0);

// ... change $buffer ...

$bytes_written = false;
if (0 === fseek($handle, $offset)) {
    $bytes_written = fwrite($handle, $buffer, $length);
}
fclose($handle);
```

If the length of `$buffer` is not fixed this will not properly work. In that case it's better to work with two files and to use [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream) as outlined in [*How to update csv column names with database table header*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13874441/367456) or if the file is not large it is also possible to do that in memory:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($filename);

// ... change $buffer ...

file_put_contents($filename, $buffer);
```