# replacing values in a file and saving

Tags: php, replace, save

I've got this bit of code which reads a file in, then goes through it line by line.

If there is a match in the line a value is updated :

```
$filePath = $_REQUEST['fn'];
$lines = file(); 
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
if(stristr($line,'Device') && stristr($line,'A=0FEDFA')) $line = str_replace ("ID=\"", "ID=\"***",$line);

if(stristr($line,'Style')) $line =  str_replace ("ID=\"", "ID=\"***",$line);
}
```

The how do I save this back as $filePath ?

Thanks

Comment: use fwrite() for write string in file try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235604/overwrite-line-in-file-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this working doing this in PHP4 :

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
if(stristr($line,'Device') && stristr($line,'A=0FEDFA')) $line[$line_num] = str_replace ("ID=\"", "ID=\"***",$line);

if(stristr($line,'Style')) $lines[$line_num] =  str_replace ("ID=\"", "ID=\"***",$line);
}
```

then using :

```
fileputcontents($filePath, ("\n", $lines))
```

and this function for PHP4

```
function fileputcontents($filename, $data)
{
 if( $file = fopen($filename, 'w') )
  {
  $bytes = fwrite($file, is_array($data) ? implode('', $data) : $data);
  fclose($file); return $bytes; // return the number of bytes written to the file
  }
}
```

All seems to be working :)

Comment: An upvote for sharing the PHP4 version for the next soul that wanders by... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

change:

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
```

to

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => &$line)
```

**Note the &** - to assign $line by reference. The changes you make to $line will then be reflected in the array containing them ($lines)

```
file_put_contents($filePath, implode("\n", $lines))
```

That line writes the altered content of the $lines array back into your file path- concatenating the elements of the array with newlines.

Comment: You don't need to do the `implode` in this case, since the array was built using `file`. `file_put_contents` will implode an array (without a glue) if one is passed as the data parameter, and the array will already have newline characters present since `file` leaves them intact in the array elements.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for setting me straight on that. I was PHPing from memory.

Comment: No problem. I had to double-check to be sure myself.

Comment: foreach ($lines as $line_num => &$line) gives an error "Parse error: parse error, unexpected '&', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in "

I'm running PHP4.

Comment: Ahhh... I see you got it working by updating the array with $lines[$line_num] rather than the reference. Good deal.