# Modify Line n With PHP?

Tags: php, file-io

I want to write on line 5 of my file.

I can't use replace because my file use many numbers in lines.
So I need to know how can modify line 5.

You know we can read line 5 of file with:

```
$File='myfile.txt';

$readline = file($File);

$line5=$readline[4];'
```

I need to code that can modify only line 5 of `$File`.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235604/overwrite-line-in-file-with-php) for how other people have done it. i would need to see a sample of what is stored in the file before answering

Comment: If you Increase your accuracy.
You'll see that I only want to change line 5.

Comment: thats not the point  is this a file for storing values, flat-filedb, logging?

Comment: I Say: "my file use many numbers in lines." at the line 2.

Comment: instead of creatively changing a certain line, make your file a key value file so that you can easily access all the information in a standardized way. done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$read` is undefined. It should be `$readline`, the following should work for you:

```
$File = 'myfile.txt';
$lines = file($File);
$lines[4] = 'modified line';
file_put_contents($File, implode("\r\n", $lines));
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a writing mistake.

Comment: @AminMaleki ok see the rest

Comment: In this code add line 6 at the end of line 5(edited line) so you need to "\r\n".
Change $lines[4] = 'modified line'; with $lines[4] = 'modified line'."\r\n";

Comment: @AminMaleki yes you right on windows it should be `\r\n` I adjusted thanks!

Comment: @meda U could better use `PHP_EOL` for line endings :)