# How to overwrite a line if starts with a specific string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a text file, called `logs.txt`, I'm trying to create a script in PHP which is supposed to check if a string which starts with `foo||` exists. If it exists, it should be replaced with a specific string, otherwise a specific string will be added at the end of the file.

This is the code I tried to make:

```
<?php

function replaceInFile($what, $with, $file){
    $buffer = "";
    $fp = file($file);
    foreach($fp as $line){
        $buffer .= preg_replace("|".$what."[A-Za-z_.]*|", $what.$with, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo $buffer;
    file_put_contents($file, $buffer);
}

replaceInFile("foo||", "foo||hello", "logs.txt");

?>
```

but it doesn't really do what I want. Can someone help me on fixing the code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look into fread() fwrite(). You're currently reading and writing the whole file, but not going through it line by line. when you find the line, you will want the pointer position so you can write to just that line.

Comment: @Chris an example is really appreciated too for a PHP beginner. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/236082/2154871

Comment: The pipe `|` needs escaping in a regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite Line in File with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235604/overwrite-line-in-file-with-php)

Comment: @Chris I'd like to look in a more elegant solution. I'll wait for other suggestions. And read better my question, it's a bit more different in this context, it's not a duplicate of that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$newline = preg_replace('/^' . $what . '(.*)$/', $with . '${1}', $line, 1 , $count);
$buffer .= ($count == 1) ? $newline : $line . $with;
```

The common Delimiters is `/` no `|` specially if you have `|` in your search criteria. Than you have to create a Capturing Group this is between `(` and `)`. Now you can use this Capturing Group and in your replacement as `${` + number of the  Capturing Group + `}`. In your case you only have one.

Comment: Will the specified string be added if no line starts with that string?

Comment: Changed it to your needs. If we did a replace than we use it if not we use the original one with `$with` at the end.